# Why can't I see my react-app through local network?

Tags: reactjs, web

I want to see my react app in my local network, but I can't. When I run `npm start` to start the local host and see my react app, it gives me two URLs. One for my current device and the other for the local network. When I open the local network URL on my phone, I just see that the page is loading. It doesn't give me any errors. I've ensured that my IP address is correct. Previously I was able to see the apps through local network, so not sure if I'm missing something trivial.

Comment: firewall perhaps?

Comment: oh your right! thanks for your help. if you like, answer my question and i'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Setting -> Network & internet -> Wi-Fi -> xyz propeties (here xyz is connected wifi name) -> Network Profile Type -> check as private
2. Firewall & network protection (search it and open it) -> Private Network -> Microsoft Defender Firewall turn off

Hope it will work...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test your ReactJS app on your phone is to Follow the following steps

1. Run your using npm start
2. After Go to the CMD in your windows machine and type the command `ipconfig` then enter that `IP address with:3000` port in your Smartphone browser
   For Example, if your IP is `192.168.1.101:3000`. the IP address should use a 3000 port
   Note:- Make sure your PC and Smartphone are Connected on the same Wifi network